# Passing func as parameter in Linq to Entities and 'Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025' error

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, lambda

We have a class called Task:

```
public partial class Task : EntityObject
{
    public EntityCollection<TaskUser> TaskUsers { get {...} set{...} } 
}
```

It has navigation property called TaskUsers, which contains users attached to this taks:

```
public partial class TaskUser : EntityObject
{
    public User User { get {...} set {  } }
}
```

Every TaskUser object has User object.

We are given `IQueryable<Task> tasks`. We want to find tasks assigned to user with ID = 1. When we use

```
tasks.Where(t => t.TaskUsers.Any(a => a.User.ID == 1))
```

everything works fine. When we use

```
Func<TaskUser, bool> function = a => a.User.ID == 1;
return tasks.Where(t => t.TaskUsers.Any(function));
```

we get nice `'Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025'` error. Why? I want to build much more complicated filters using `Expression` class, but if I can't pass simple `Func`, this can't be done. What should I do?

**EDIT**

Maybe

```
Func<TaskUser, bool> function = a => a.User.ID == 1;
return tasks.Where(t => t.TaskUsers.Any(function));
```

doesn't work, but

```
Expression<Func<TaskUser, bool>> expression = a => a.User.ID == 1;
return tasks.Where(t => t.TaskUsers.AsQueryable().Any(expression));
```

works! That is all I needed.

Comment: Heh, I just posted a bounty on a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990158/internal-net-framework-data-provider-error-1025), before finding your solution here.  Wanna go grab the bounty?

Comment: Actually, having tried using `Expression` rather than `Func`, like you did, mine did **not** work.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well the EF can only translate Expressions, not functions.

i.e. it can translate this:

```
Expression<Func<TaskUser,bool>>
```

but not this:

```
Func<TaskUser,bool>
```

As for how to merge expressions (in pseudo code):

```
Expression<Func<TaskUser, bool>> expression = a => a.User.ID == 1;
return tasks.Where(t => t.TaskUsers.Any(expression));
```

There are probably some Expression guru's who can help with that.

I suggest a followup question focused on that particular problem

Alex

Comment: Without help of guru: return tasks.Where(t => t.TaskUsers.AsQueryable().Any(expression));