# Group by Dynamic Aggregate

Tags: linq, expression-trees

In the code below I want to replace `x.BaseSalary` with any other property whose name is stored in `feildtoretrive`:

```
var feildtoretrive  = "BaseSalary"
var groupcal = db.Employees.GroupBy(x=>x.Region)
                           .Select(group => new { 
                                    Key = group.Key, 
                                    Avg = group.Average(x => x.BaseSalary) 
                                                })
                           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to

- create a `MemberExpression` that accesses that member of an instance
- compile a lambda expression that returns that member for a passed instance parameter

(I assume that the elements in `Employees` are of type `Employee`)

```
// the parameter expression for the lambda (your 'x')
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee));
// the property access expression (your 'x.BaseSalary' or 'x.<feildtoretrive')
var propAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, feildtoretrive);
// the build-together and compiled lambda
 var expression = (Expression<Func<Employee, int?>>)Expression.Lambda(propAccess, parameter);
```

You can now use `lambda` for the `x.Average` call:

```
new { Key = group.Key, Avg = group.Average(lambda) }
```

A caveat: This only works now for members of type `int?`. I'm lacking a little experience on how to do this more type independent, but what types can you calculate an average over? But if there are `int` or `double` members, another cast expression maybe necessary.

---

EDIT: (changed the return type to `int?`). According to [Ivan Stoev's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419910/notsupportedexception-when-using-compiled-lambda-expression-for-average?noredirect=1#comment83833048_48419910) on my follow up question you could try this:

```
new { Key = group.Key, Avg = group.AsQueryable().Average(expression) }
```

**EF6** should recognize the call to `AsQueryable()` and then use the correct `Average` method (note that I use the `expression` as argument instead of the `lambda`). EF Core and linq2Sql *won't* work with that.

Comment: You can address the caveat by using reflection to cast the `Delegate` returned by `Expression.Compile` to a `Func<Employee,T>` of the correct `T` based on the type of the `failedtoretrieve` Property.  Then you would reflectively invoke `IGrouping.Average` passing the the result of the reflective cast in the `parameters` object array.

Comment: It Throws runtime "
Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 102"

Comment: @user3815413 it seems the query provider has problems to translate this to sql. Just to be sure: did it work "before" (just using `x => x.BaseSalary`)?

Comment: @user3815413 I edited the answer for an easier/shorter way to create the property access expression. It _may_ solve your issue, but I think it may rather have something to do with the types of the properties. Is the property you tested with of type `decimal`?

Comment: Yes it worked without any issue iwth (just using x => x.BaseSalary)
Properties are of type int

Comment: Properties are of type Int32? (nullable)

Comment: @user3815413 if they are `int?`, then try changing it to `var lambda = (Func<Employee, int?>)Expresssion.....` instead.

Comment: That i changed already but it throws Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 102,
Since cox this is Linq to EF?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it...and I currently don't have time to reproduce this in detail. I didn't find anything on goolge for that error message (maybe because it's "internal")....my last idea would be that there is a cast expression missing and that causes the query translator to fail...I'll see if I find time today to check that....

Comment: @user3815413 as a workaround you could insert a `AsEnumerable()` after the `GroupBy` and before the `Select`. But that would mean that all columns are transferred from the db to your memory and the average is calculated on your cpu instead of by the db..... I don't know why it doesn't work, in Linq2Sql it complains that the overload of `Average` was not supported, but (according to the compiler) it's the same overload as with `x => x.BaseSalary`...

Comment: @user3815413 now I'm really curious and asked a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419910/notsupportedexception-when-using-compiled-lambda-expression-for-average) myself.

Comment: AsEnumerable(),
This is already done but since data is huge i dont want to bring anything to memory,
That is the reason i wanted to go for expressions

Comment: @user3815413 I updated again with a version that _should_ work in EF6, but won't in linq2sql or EF Core, Don't know the exact framework you're using.

Comment: Now also  i am getting the error code
"Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025".

I am using EF6

Comment: **1025**? You said "102" before! But for 1025, `AsQueryable` should work according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765269/casting-linq-expression-throws-internal-net-framework-data-provider-error-1025) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990158/internal-net-framework-data-provider-error-1025) and the other google results. Guess I'm out now, seems I can't find a working solution for you.

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot René Vogt,
As per advice after remvoing compile and converting to expression worked for EF now,
Thanks a lot @René Vogt,

Comment: @user3815413 phew... you're welcoome, thank god it works :) I finally think I understand why my first version didn't....

Comment: @user3815413 so if we finally solved it, you may reaccept the answer if you like :)